# Spring Keycloak: Get User ID

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I have developed a Spring Boot Webservice and use Keycloak for Access Management. 
The website stores some userdata in a database. I try to connect these data with the user logged in.

At the moment I store the username with the data. But I like to store the user id instead the username. How can I do that?

I try to get SecurityContext by this:

```
@Bean
@Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public KeycloakSecurityContext getKeycloakSecurityContext() {
    return ((KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>) getRequest().getUserPrincipal()).getKeycloakSecurityContext();
}
```

But I get an error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.getKeycloakSecurityContext'
defined in com.SiteApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method
failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
instantiate [org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext]: Factory method
'getKeycloakSecurityContext' threw exception; nested exception is
java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken
cannot be cast to org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal
```

Is this the right way? What is missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

I found a much simpler solution than the above:

```
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity getEndpoint(String someParam, HttpServletRequest request) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationToken principal = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal();
        String userId = principal.getAccount().getKeycloakSecurityContext().getIdToken().getSubject();

        //....do something

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I think the exception you are getting above is because you are trying to cast `getRequest().getUserPrincipal()` to `KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>` while it is of type `KeycloakAuthenticationToken`, so `((KeycloakAuthenticationToken) getRequest().getUserPrincipal())` would work.

Comment: thx, thats it: final String keycloakUuid=getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getSubject().intern();

Answer (score 12):

I've done something similar in our code.

```
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Expecting a HTTP request");
            }

            RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext context = (RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext) request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());

            if (context == null) {
                handleNoSecurityContext(request, response, chain);
                return;
            }

            AccessToken accessToken = context.getToken();
            Integer userId = Integer.parseInt(accessToken.getOtherClaims().get("user_id").toString());

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

}
```

Before you can do this you must add the `user_id` to the access tokens being issued by keycloak. You can do this through a mapper as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: configuration for property mapper]

Also, don't forgot to add the processing filter from above to your application lifecycle by adding a `@Bean` method to your application class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {FallbackWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class, SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan
@EnableAsync
public class MyServiceClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyServiceClass.class)
                .properties(properties)
                .bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF)
                .run(args);
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter authFilter() {
        return new AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, how do you make it a *integer*? I think the id is a UUID which is not a int but a String... Thanks!

Comment: I also want to have an integer id since it is much more convenient

Comment: Hi, ah! You're right, it's a UUID. We don't use the UUID. We create a separate user_id attribute that is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

All solutions above are using the (very) [deprecated Keycloak Spring adapters](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187), which was a solution 2 years ago, but isn't anymore.

2 Alternatives to Keycloak Spring adapters, both having very easy way to access-token claims from `Authentication` "auto-magically" injected by Spring as `@Controller` method parameter.

### `spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server`

[Sample here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication): almost everything configurable from properties

```java
    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public ResponseEntity getEndpoint(OAuthentication<OpenidClaimSet> auth) {
        final var preferredUsername = auth.getClaims().getPreferredUsername();
        final var subject = auth.getClaims().getSubject();
        //....do something
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

### `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`

[Sample there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken): requires much more Java config

```java
    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public ResponseEntity getEndpoint(JwtAuthenticationToken auth) {
        final var preferredUsername = auth.getToken().getClaimAsString(StandardClaimNames.SUB);
        final var subject = auth.getToken().getClaimAsString(StandardClaimNames.PREFERRED_USERNAME);
        //....do something
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```